# Keybord interface design in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am new to Verilog and I am trying to create one of my first programs which should display something when key on keybord is pressed. I'd like to use example code from Verilog coursebook, but I have some problems with pin assingment (I use DE2-70 from Altera).

1. Why I have `input ReadKB;` while there is nothing like this in module definition?
2. I know which pins should be assign to KBclk and KBdata. (`PS2_KBCLK PIN_F24 PS/2 Clock` and (`PS2_KBDAT PIN_E24 PS/2 Data`) What about ResetKB?

In the coursebook there is no explanation and I am really courious about it.

Code:

```
module KeyboardInterface(KBclk, KBdata, ResetKB, SYNclk, ScanRdy, ScanCode, KeyReleased);
input KBclk;
input KBdata; 
input ResetKB;
input ReadKB;
input SYNclk;
output ScanRdy;
output ScanCode; 
output KeyReleased;

    //Generate an internal synchronized clock
    reg Clock;
    always @(posedge SYNclk) Clock = KBclk;

    reg[3:0] BitCount;
    reg StartBitDetected, ScanRdy;
    reg[7:0] ScanCode;


    //Count the number of serial bits and collect data into ScanCode
    always @(posedge Clock) begin
        if(ResetKB) begin
            BitCount=0; StartBitDetected =0;
        end else begin
            if(KBdata == 0 && StartBitDetected == 0) begin
                StartBitDetected=1;
                ScanRdy = 0;
            end else if (StartBitDetected) begin
                if(BitCount < 8) begin
                    BitCount = BitCount + 1;
                    ScanCode = {KBdata, ScanCode[7:1]};
                end else begin
                    StartBitDetected = 0;
                    BitCount = 0;
                    ScanRdy = 1;
                end
            end
        end
    end



    reg [1:0] CompletionState;
    wire KeyReleased;

        //keep track of the state of Scan Codes outputted
    always @(posedge SYNclk) begin
        if(ResetKB) CompletionState = 0;

        else case(CompletionState)
            0: if(ScanCode == 8'h70 && ScanRdy == 1) CompletionState =1;
                else CompletionState =0;
            1:  if(ScanRdy == 1) CompletionState =1;
                else CompletionState =2;
            2: if(ScanRdy == 0) CompletionState = 2;
                else CompletionState = 0;
            3: CompletionState = 0;
        endcase
    end

    assign KeyReleased = CompletionState == 3 ? 1 : 0; 

endmodule
```

Thank you!

Comment: #1 looks like a typo, just go ahead and add the missing wire to the module defn. I don't understand #2; what do you mean "I can find pins", what setup are you working with exactly?

Comment: @Tim, I've edited my question. I mean: I know which pins should be assigned.

Comment: There's probably not actually a 'reset' coming from your keyboard if that's what you're asking. I'd just tie it to some pushbutton on the Altera if it is available.

Comment: @Tim could you post an answer (not a comment) to let me accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That looks like a typo, just go ahead and add the missing wire to the module definition.
2. There's probably not actually a 'reset' coming from your keyboard if that's what you're asking. I'd just tie it to some pushbutton on the Altera if it is available.

Comment: I still have a little problem. I would like to do `assign left = (ScanCode == 8'h1C)` or set `left` (an output) homehow to 1, but only if key is being pressed. What can I do?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You've told me what assign you'd like to write, why don't you just do that? I fail to see where your problem is. Perhaps you could elaborate or (preferrably) file a new question.

Comment: OK, I'll try. I just have some problems in saying what I need in English. I would like to have 1 when key 1C is being pressed and 0 when it is not being pressed. This assignment doesn't work like this (1 remains when key is released). Is there anything I can add to this assignment or change in code?

Comment: Have you looked at this in a simulation? I assume you must get some notification on the inputs when a key is released. You'll need to interpret this release input to have it change the value of scancode, or notify you in some other way that the key is no longer being pressed.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a high-level reset signal. You can just connect it with a push button, then you can use the push button to reset the reg signals, bitcount and startbitdetect.

But one crucial thing you should note is that reg signals can not use "=" inside the always section, it should be "<=". This is the difference between blocking and non-blocking assignment that you should pay more attentions on. Good luck.:-)

Comment: *that reg signals can not use "=" inside the always section*. They certainly can use `=` inside an always block. You're correct that that is the difference between blocking and non-blocking, but there's nothing wrong with using blocking statements (for setting intermediate signals, for example).

Comment: Does it cause that key code remains in ScanCode after key is released? I would like to do `assign left = (ScanCode == 8'h1C)`, but only if key is being pressed. What can I do?